# Increase all employees' salaries for a classification by 5.65% percent, others by 4.93% percent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm in school currently and I have an individual project needing to increase all employees with my selected job classification by 5.65% and everyone else by 4.93%. Here is what I have so far...

```
UPDATE Employee 
 SET Salary = Salary * 0.0565
WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM Employee
                      INNER JOIN Job
                         ON Employee.Job_ID = job.Job_ID
                            AND job.Job_Classification = 'Retail Sales'
                WHERE Job.Job_ID = Employee.Job_ID
              );
```

---

My question is, is there a way I can put it so that it increases everyone by 5.65% and everyone else within the same script? I'm feeling like it's an `IF THEN ELSE` kinda thing but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Be very careful. You can use the same table multiple times within a single query and, by default, each reference to the table is independent. Meaning that the reference to `Employee` within your subquery will not be referencing the *same* rows as the reference to `Employee` in the outer query. Meaning your current query is "update *every* employee's salary by 5.65% if there exists *any* employee who work in Retail Sales"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Christopher Trevor said, it should be something like this:

```
UPDATE e 
  SET e.Salary = 
        case when job.Job_Classification = 'Retail Sales' 
             then e.Salary * 0.0565 
             else e.Salary * 0.0493 
         end
from Employee e
inner join Job job on job.Job_ID = e.Job_ID
```

I have not tested this because you haven't posted the schema for the tables. But it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the case statement.

Basic syntax would be:

```
UPDATE Employees
 SET Salary = CASE Classification WHEN 'Retail Sales' THEN Do 5.65% ELSE Do 4.93%
```

You would most likely need to include a join in your update to get the classification from the Jobs table.

The above syntax is not correct but should give you enough of a direction to go further

Comment: Plus 1 for Correct logic ;)